# Searching for late '80s/early '90s AD&D book of modules with specific encounters

Tags: published-adventures, product-identification, adnd-1e, books

Back in the late 80s or early 90s, I purchased an AD&D book containing a dozen or more goofy/silly one-shot modules.  I gave this book away as a birthday present, but I'm trying to remember what that book was called.

For instance, one module was crashing some Kobold's party(?) where the Kobold bad guy summoned some kind of demon during a dinner party, then animated all of the roasted chickens to dance around for entertainment, and ultimately ticked off the demon to the point where it attacks everybody.

This same module had the characters randomly being approached by a flesh golem in a tuxedo (i.e., Lurch from Adams Family) with a tray full of mice head (or headless mice) hors d'oeuvres that the players were expected to take, but not necessarily eat.

Another module was some kind of circus, I think, where one encounter had a tank full of playful dolphins that enticed the players to join them, but ultimately the dolphins were carnivorous.

Also, I think there may have been some kind of adventure or encounter involving animated objects like puppets (i.e., Pinocchio).

I don't know if this book was specific to a particular setting, but I do recall we used it for AD&D.

Comment: This _sounds like_ WG7, the joke version of Castle Greyhawk.  I have run parts of it and these particular scenarios did not appear, but they are consistent with the theme and may be in the parts I haven't run.  If no one answers definitively in a bit I can dig it out and confirm or reject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The module you are talking about is WG7 World of Greyhawk Fantasy World Adventure Castle Greyhawk. Chapter 2 is the one you mentioned, "Level 2: It's my Party and I'll Die if I want to".

Monsters include: Goblin Butchers, Headless Mouse Horde, Giant Frog, Baby Bugbear, Flesh Golem Butler, Frantic Orc, Ogre Guards, Garbage Collector, Dish Carrier, Magical Broom. The demon is Asmodeus arch-devil.

There are 12 chapters of silly adventures.

1. Against the Little Guys
2. It's My Party and I'll Die if I Want To
3. Too Many Cooks
4. There's No Place like Up
5. The Name of the Game
6. The Temple of Really Bad Dead Things
7. Queen of the Honeybee Hive
8. Of Kings and Colonels
9. Vices N Virtues
10. Fluffy Goes Down the Drain
11. Mordenkainen's Movie Madness
12. Where the Random Monsters Roam

[image: WG7 Castle Greyhawk]

Comment: The cover is exactly how I remember it!